# Using same model class for two SQL tables with identical schema

Tags: azure-sql-database, dbcontext, dbset, ef-core-5.0

I am using EF Core 5 and I have an Azure SQL server with 2 tables that have identical schemas.

The tables are (pseudo SQL):

```
Table1 (
         ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
         Date datetime2(0),
         Title varchar(100)
       )

Table2 (
         ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
         Date datetime2(0),
         Title varchar(100)
       )
```

And my classes are like so:

```
public class TableRecord
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext() { }

    public MyContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
        // This is for Managed Identity, ignore.
        var connection = (SqlConnection)Database.GetDbConnection();
        connection.AccessToken = new AzureServiceTokenProvider().GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/").Result;
    }
    
    public virtual DbSet<TableRecord> Table1 { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<TableRecord> Table2 { get; set; }
}
```

and to get data I do:

```
// context is an instance of "MyContext" with SqlOptions passed in.
var results = context.Table1.Where(x => x.Title.Contains("asd")).ToList();
```

however this gives me the error:
`Invalid object name 'TableRecord'.`

If I just copy-paste the `TableRecord` class and rename both classes to something like `Table1Record` and `Table2Record` and change it so Table1's DbSet is of type "Table1Record" and similarly for Table2, it works. But it is annoying.

Is there any way to tell EF Core that there are two separate tables, as I have defined them as two separate properties of the DbContext, but they have the same schema, so I want to use the same class for both of them?

Comment: Avoid using the term "schema" - within databases it's a very overloaded term with many different meanings so it's not universally clear what you're referring to (e.g. a SQL Server `SCHEMA`  is completely unrelated to a MySQL `schema` - and in neither case does it refer to the _design_ of a table.

Comment: It sounds like your project is database-first instead of code-first - in that case you don't need to define entity types by-hand. Instead use something like [EF POCO](https://github.com/sjh37/EntityFramework-Reverse-POCO-Code-First-Generator) to generate and maintain generated entity classes  - I find EF Core's built-in scaffolding generator is really lacking.

Comment: "Is there any way to tell EF Core that there are two separate tables, as I have defined them as two separate properties of the DbContext, but they have the same schema, so I want to use the same class for both of them?" - No. That's by-design. The _type_ of an entity is how EF knows what database table entity instances belong to.